# Testing whether an object is a Java primitive array in Clojure

Tags: arrays, reflection, clojure, primitive-types

What's the best way to detect whether an object is a Java primitive array in Clojure?

The reason I need this is to do some special handling for primitive arrays, which might look something like:

```
  (if (byte-array? object)
    (handle-byte-array object))
```

It's in a fairly performance-sensitive piece of code so I'd rather avoid reflection if at all possible.

Comment: Not sure what the Clojure code would be, but you could create an empty array for every primitive type, call getClass() on those, and cache the results. The Class object should be the same for every array of that primitive type – you'd compare the cached ones with `object.getClass()`. (getClass() shouldn't really be a slow call)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use reflection once to get the class from the name, cache this and then
compare the rest to that

```
(def array-of-ints-type (Class/forName "[I"))
(def array-of-bytes-type (Class/forName "[B")) 
...

(= (type (into-array Integer/TYPE [1 3 4])) array-of-ints-type)
true
```

Comment: Nice, like the idea of caching the primitive array classes. Though it does strike me as a bit off that these aren't already defined somewhere in Java!

Comment: `"[J"` for `long`s is even more endearing, isn't it? Also, whoever came up with the unmatched opening brackets in `.toString` return values, anytime I learn their name, my pitchfork will be ready. It breaks paredit for me all the time, not to mention [the effect on my psyche](http://xkcd.com/859/). (Replacing `print-method` for all the relevant cases may or may not be feasible -- my current gut feeling is *not*.)

Answer (score 7):

```
(defn primitive-array? [o]
  (let [c (class o)]
    (and (.isArray c)
         (.. c getComponentType isPrimitive))))
```

For particular cases, you could use something like the following:

```
(defn long-array? [o]
  (let [c (class o)]
    (and (.isArray c)
         (identical? (.getComponentType c) Long/TYPE))))
```

Comment: All secrets are laid bare: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 7):

To check for a byte array without the use of reflection you can do this:

```
(def ^:const byte-array-type (type (byte-array 0)))
(defn bytes? [x] (= (type x) byte-array-type))
```

Not exactly sure why, but you can even inline the byte-array-type with `^:const`.

Answer (score 5):

Or plain old `instance?`:

```
(instance? (RT/classForName "[B") thing)
```

Comment: What alias are you using for `RT`? You mean `(Class/forName "[B")` right?

Comment: @DavidJames RT is clojure.lang.RT.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed by Arthur Ulfeldt, you can use `Class/forName`, for example, like here:

```
(def byte_array_class (Class/forName "[B"))

(defn byte-array? [arr] (instance? byte_array_class arr))
```

If you want to avoid magic strings like `"[B"` when caching the classes, you can apply `class` to an existing array object:

```
(def byte_array_class (class (byte-array [])))
```

Comment: Even simpler: `(def byte-array-class (class (byte-array 0)))`. (No underscores either!)

Answer (score 3):

Props to all the other answers.  Here it is as a one-liner:

```
(def byte-array? (partial instance? (Class/forName "[B")))
```

For other primitives, refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29 (or the java spec).  Or just do what Gerrit suggests with `(type (xyz-array 0))`.  Specifically you can use:

```
"[Z" boolean array
"[B" byte array
"[C" char array
"[D" double array
"[F" float array
"[I" integer array
"[J" long array
"[S" short array
```

Since performance was mentioned, here's a small benchmark result of running `(time (dotimes [_ 500000] (byte-array? x)))`, and with `byte-array-class` def'd

```
(def byte-array? (partial instance? (Class/forName "[B")))
78.518335 msecs
(defn byte-array? [obj] (instance? byte-array-class obj))
34.879537 msecs
(defn byte-array? [obj] (= (type obj) byte-array-class))
49.68781 msecs
```

`instance?` vs `type` = instance? wins

`partial` vs `defn` = defn wins

but any of these approaches will likely not be a bottleneck in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Since Clojure 1.9, you can use `bytes?` [bytes? doc link](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/bytes?)