# how to check if a clojure object is a byte-array?

Tags: clojure

How would one write the function `bytes?` that returns the following:

```
(bytes? [1 2 3]) ;; => false
(bytes? (byte-array 8)) ;; => true
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(defn bytes? [x]
  (if (nil? x)
    false
    (= (Class/forName "[B")
       (.getClass x))))
```

**Update.** The same question has been already asked here [Testing whether an object is a Java primitive array in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090396/testing-whether-an-object-is-a-java-primitive-array-in-clojure). And google gives exactly that page on your question "how to check if a clojure object is a byte-array?" ;)

Comment: The 'forName' part is very inefficient and implementation-dependent. Nielsk's answer is faster and more robust.

Comment: @dimagog is right. Instead of editing the code I would just like to note that `(Class/forName "[B")` can be moved into a var like `(def ^{:private true} bytes-class (Class/forName "[B"))`. This was you pay var dereferencing cost instead of reflection cost at runtime. I don't know which one is worse. Also AFAIK `^:const` doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 12):

The way I used to do this until now was creating an array of that type and testing for it's class. To prevent creating an unnecessary instance every time, make a function that closes over the class of that particular array type.

```
(defn test-array
  [t]
  (let [check (type (t []))]
    (fn [arg] (instance? check arg))))

(def byte-array?
  (test-array byte-array))

=> (byte-array? (byte-array 8))
true

=> (byte-array? [1 2 3])
false
```

Mobyte's example seems a lot simpler though, and it seems I'll have some refactoring to do where I used this :)

Comment: No answer is entitled to upvotes: people like what they like. In my experience, complaining about lack of votes discourages them still more.

Comment: @NielsK I've upvoted your answer. Not because of your solicitation though, but because it's better :-).

Answer (score 6):

Clojure.core version 1.9 onwards supports a `bytes?` function. Here's the [Clojuredocs link](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/bytes_q)